# Python: how to compare the similarity between clustering using k-means algorithm?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have two observations of the same event. Let say `X` and `Y`.
I suppose to have `nc` clusters. I am using `sklearn` to make the clustering.

```
x = KMeans(n_clusters=nc).fit_predict(X)
y = KMeans(n_clusters=nc).fit_predict(Y)
```

is there a measure that allow me to compare `x` and `y`: i.e. this measure will be `1` if the clusters `x` and `y` are the same.

Answer (score 2):

Just extract the cluster centers of your kmeans-objects (see the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html)):

```
x_centers = x.cluster_centers_
y_centers = y.cluster_centers_
```

The you have to decide which metric you are using to compare these. Keep in mind that the centers are floating-points, the clustering-process is a heuristic and the clustering-process is a random-algorithm. This means, you will get something which interprets as *not exactly the same* with a high probability, even for cluster-objects trained on the same data.

This [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95782/what-are-the-most-common-metrics-for-comparing-two-clustering-algorithms-especi) discusses some approaches and the problems.

Answer (score 1):

The Rand Index and its adjusted version do this exactly.  Two cluster assignments that match (even if the labels themselves, which are treated as arbitrary, are different), get a score of 1.  A value of 0 means they don't agree at all.  The Adjusted Rand Index uses its baseline as random assignment of points to clusters.

Comment: would Adjusted Rand of just Rand make more sense in the OP case?

Comment: @serafeim what is OP?

Comment: original post = OP